# Memory leak by ctypes pointers used within python class

Tags: python, pointers, memory-leaks, ctypes

I try to wrap some C code via ctypes. Altough, my code (attached below) is functional, [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) suggests it is suffering a memory leak somewhere. The basic C struct, I'm trying to wrap is defined in 'image.h'. It defines an image object, containing a pointer to the data, a pointer array (needed for various other functions not included here), along with some shape information.

**image.h**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct image {
double * data;    /*< The main pointer to the image data*/
i3_flt **row;     /*< An array of pointers to each row of the image*/
unsigned long n;  /*< The total number of pixels in the image*/
unsigned long nx; /*< The number of pixels per row (horizontal image dimensions)*/
unsigned long ny; /*< The number of pixels per column (vertical image dimensions)*/
} image;
```

The python code that wraps this C struct via ctypes is contained in 'image_wrapper.py' below. The python class *Image* implements many more methods which I didn't include here. The idea is to have a python object, that is as convenient to use as a numpy array. In fact, the class contains a numpy array as an attribute (self.array) which points to the exact same memory location than the data pointer within the C struct.

**image_wrapper.py**:

```
import numpy
import ctypes as c

class Image(object):

    def __init__(self, nx, ny):

        self.nx = nx
        self.ny = ny
        self.n = nx * ny
        self.shape = tuple((nx, ny))
        self.array = numpy.zeros((nx, ny), order='C', dtype=c.c_double)
        self._argtype = self._argtype_generator()
        self._update_cstruct_from_array()

    def _update_cstruct_from_array(self):

        data_pointer = self.array.ctypes.data_as(c.POINTER(c.c_double))

        ctypes_pointer = c.POINTER(c.c_double) * self.ny
        row_pointers = ctypes_pointer(
            *[self.array[i,:].ctypes.data_as(c.POINTER(c.c_double)) for i in range(self.ny)])

        ctypes_pointer = c.POINTER(ctypes_pointer)
        row_pointer = ctypes_pointer(row_pointers)

        self._cstruct = c.pointer(self._argtype(data=data_pointer,
                                                row=row_pointer,
                                                n=self.n,
                                                nx=self.nx,
                                                ny=self.ny))

    def _argtype_generator(self):

        class _Argtype(c.Structure):
            _fields_ = [("data", c.POINTER(c.c_double)),
                        ("row", c.POINTER(c.POINTER(c.c_double) * self.ny)),
                        ("n", c.c_ulong),
                        ("nx", c.c_ulong),
                        ("ny", c.c_ulong)]

        return _Argtype
```

Now, testing the memory consumption of the above code with memory_profiler suggests that Python's garbage collector is unable to clean up all references. Here is my test code, that creates a variable number of class instances within loops of different sizes.

**test_image_wrapper.py**

```
import sys
import image_wrapper as img
import numpy as np 

@profile
def main(argv):
    image_size = 500

    print 'Create 10 images\n'
    for i in range(10):
        x = img.Image(image_size, image_size)
        del x

    print 'Create 100 images\n'
    for i in range(100):
        x = img.Image(image_size, image_size)
        del x

    print 'Create 1000 images\n'
    for i in range(1000):
        x = img.Image(image_size, image_size)
        del x

    print 'Create 10000 images\n'
    for i in range(10000):
        x = img.Image(image_size, image_size)
        del x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

The @profile is telling memory_profiler to analyse the subsequent function, here main. Running python with memory_profiler on test_image_wrapper.py via

```
python -m memory_profiler test_image_wrapper.py
```

yields the following output:

```
Filename: test_image_wrapper.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    49                             @profile
    50                             def main(argv):
    51                                 """
    52                                 Script to test memory usage of image.py
    53    16.898 MB     0.000 MB       """
    54    16.898 MB     0.000 MB       image_size = 500
    55                             
    56    16.906 MB     0.008 MB       print 'Create 10 images\n'
    57    19.152 MB     2.246 MB       for i in range(10):
    58    19.152 MB     0.000 MB           x = img.Image(image_size, image_size)
    59    19.152 MB     0.000 MB           del x
    60                             
    61    19.152 MB     0.000 MB       print 'Create 100 images\n'
    62    19.512 MB     0.359 MB       for i in range(100):
    63    19.516 MB     0.004 MB           x = img.Image(image_size, image_size)
    64    19.516 MB     0.000 MB           del x
    65                             
    66    19.516 MB     0.000 MB       print 'Create 1000 images\n'
    67    25.324 MB     5.809 MB       for i in range(1000):
    68    25.328 MB     0.004 MB           x = img.Image(image_size, image_size)
    69    25.328 MB     0.000 MB           del x
    70                             
    71    25.328 MB     0.000 MB       print 'Create 10000 images\n'
    72    83.543 MB    58.215 MB       for i in range(10000):
    73    83.543 MB     0.000 MB           x = img.Image(image_size, image_size)
    74                                     del x
```

Each instance of the class Image within python seems to leave about 5-6kB, summing up to ~58MB when processing 10k images. For an individual object this seems not much, but as I have to run on ten millions, I do care. The line that seems to cause the leak is the following contained in image_wrapper.py.

```
        self._cstruct = c.pointer(self._argtype(data=data_pointer,
                                                row=row_pointer,
                                                n=self.n,
                                                nx=self.nx,
                                                ny=self.ny))
```

As mentioned above, it seems Python's garbage collector is unable to clean up all references. I did try to implement my own *del* function, something like

```
def __del__(self):
    del self._cstruct
    del self
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to fix the issue. After spending a day of researching and trying several memory debuggers, my last resort seems stackoverflow. Many thanks for your valuable thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: What version of `numpy` are you using? (`import numpy; print numpy.version.version`)

Comment: And you are 100% that the leak is in the usage of `ctypes` and not of your C code? AFAIK it will be easier for you and anybody on SO if you could provide a minimal implementation that shows the problem so that we can try to find the culprit. Most of the time I solve the bugs I find in my code doing this before posting on SO.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.3 and Numpy version 1.6.1. The python script test_image_wrapper.py never calls the C code. I just included image.h for clarity. Therefore, I'm pretty confident that the problem is caused by the ctypes pointers set to self.array with the python class Image.

Answer (score 3):

It may not be the only issue, but for sure the caching of each `_Argtype`: `LP__Argtype` pair in the dict `_ctypes._pointer_type_cache` is not insignificant. Memory usage should go down if you `clear` the cache.

The pointer and function type caches can be cleared with `ctypes._reset_cache()`. Bear in mind that clearing the cache can cause problems. For example:

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes

c_double_p = POINTER(c_double)
c_double_pp = POINTER(c_double_p)

class Image(Structure): 
    _fields_ = [('row', c_double_pp)]

ctypes._reset_cache()
nc_double_p = POINTER(c_double)
nc_double_pp = POINTER(nc_double_p)
```

The old pointers still work with `Image`:

```
>>> img = Image((c_double_p * 10)()) 
>>> img = Image(c_double_pp(c_double_p(c_double())))
```

New pointers created after resetting the cache won't work:

```
>>> img = Image((nc_double_p * 10)())

TypeError: incompatible types, LP_c_double_Array_10 instance 
  instead of LP_LP_c_double instance

>>> img = Image(nc_double_pp(nc_double_p(c_double())))

TypeError: incompatible types, LP_LP_c_double instance 
  instead of LP_LP_c_double instance
```

---

If resetting the cache solves your problem, maybe that's good enough. But generally the pointer cache is both necessary and beneficial, so personally I'd look for another way. For example, as far as I can see there's no reason to customize `_Argtype` for each image. You could just define `row` as a `double **` initialized to the array of pointers.

Comment: Resetting the cache by calling `ctypes._reset_cache()` helps. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation online or within the ctypes package. It feels a bit like a blackbox as I can only guess what it does. For example, what happens if two `Image` objects are simultaneously alive, only one of which I want to delete? Is there a ctypes function to free individual pointers? How can I clear only those pointers that belong to a certain object? Also, I can't define _Argtype globally, as @HYRY suggested too, because I only know at runtime what the size of the image is unfortunately.

Comment: The problems I pointed out were general. It may not be an issue for you if use `del _ctypes._pointer_type_cache[self._argtype]` after creating the pointer instead of clearing everything. I still don't understand why you need to set the row pointer to a specific size. The array of pointers can be assigned to a generic `double **` field. In Python you're using the NumPy array, no? i.e. isn't the struct just for calling C functions that operate on the data?

Comment: Now I see what you're saying. True,

Comment: .., defining `_Argtype` as a generic `double **` should work. Thanks for pointing me to the function `ctypes._pointer_type_cache`. I'll give it a try by rewriting my code above and report back asap.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using Python 2.7.3 and Numpy version 1.6.1.

I suspect the culprit is this line...

```
self.array = numpy.zeros((nx, ny), order='C', dtype=c.c_double)
```

According to [this ticket](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/585), there's a memory leak in `numpy.zeroes()` in version 1.6, which was apparently fixed in version 1.7.

Comment: I did replace numpy.zeros with numpy.empty, however the memory leak remains. Commenting line self._update_cstruct_from_array() fixes the memory issue, indicating that the problem is likely to be related to the pointer arithmetics therein. That's why I suspect ctypes and uncleared references to cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating one `_Argtype` class object for every Image object. Move the define of `_Argtype` to the global scope will solve this memory leak.

You can comfirm this by append the following line to your test code:

```
print len(c.Structure.__subclasses__())
```

**EDIT**

as @eryksun said ctypes caches all the POINTER class in a dict, you can confirm this by following line:

```
print c._pointer_type_cache
```

Comment: The `_Argtype` wouldn't be retained in memory except for the pointer-type cache that I discussed.